# Programmatically select an item in combobox by using its ValueMember property

Tags: c#, combobox, valuemember

I have a method that gets the `ComboBox` object and the query to be loaded on its items.

The method also asks for 2 other items:

1.The DB table's column name and sets it into the `Combobox`'s `DisplayMember` property

2.The id of each record under that DB table column name and sets it into the `Combobox`'s `ValueMember` property

```
public void DatabaseColumnRecordsToCombobox(ComboBox cbx, String query, String displayMember, String valueMember)
{
    try
    {
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        tbl = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(tbl);
        cbx.DataSource = tbl;
        cbx.DisplayMember = displayMember;
        cbx.ValueMember = valueMember;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        this.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

I use the method by creating a query with 2 columns, the Id and its corresponding Name. And storing it in the `ComboBox`'s `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`:

```
DatabaseColumnRecordsToCombobox(cmbSupplier, "SELECT Id, Supplier_Name FROM Supplier WHERE Enable_Flag=1 ORDER BY Supplier_Name", "Supplier_Name", "Id");
```

I apologize for the long introduction, I just want you all to understand how my program works before telling my problem. So the problem is how do I select the default item of `DataGridView` by using the `ComboBox`'s `ValueMember` property?

All I know in programatically selecting an item is by using `cmbCategory.SelectedItem = "Supplier A"` but what I need is to select by using the `ValueMember`. This way I can set the default item by Id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use SelectedValue instead:

```
comboBox1.SelectedValue = "2";
```

A very simple example just to show what i mean:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Clear();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id");
        dt.Columns.Add("Supplier_Name");
        DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
        r["Id"] = "1";
        r["Supplier_Name"] = "Supplier A";
        dt.Rows.Add(r);
        r = dt.NewRow();
        r["Id"] = "2";
        r["Supplier_Name"] = "Supplier B";
        dt.Rows.Add(r);
        r = dt.NewRow();
        r["Id"] = "3";
        r["Supplier_Name"] = "Supplier C";
        dt.Rows.Add(r);

        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Supplier_Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";

        //This will set the ComboBox to "Supplier B"
        comboBox1.SelectedValue = "2";
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! But just want to know if it's okay to use an integer for combobox1.SelectedValue? e.g. `comboBox1.SelectedValue = 1`. I used an integer and it still worked, just don't know why this went okay. By the way, I love you man! #nohomo

Comment: Ha ha no problem man! An integer should work as well since its an object type. You should be able to use the same type as the type you have in your ValueMember.